# Encoding UIView contents in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, svg

I have currently implemented a screen which subclasses a `UIView` which customers can draw their signature on using `CGContext` (to be sent to a `server`).

**What would be the best way to encode this data?**

I am hoping to use `SVG` to upload to the server.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can encode it any way you wish, I would have suggested png, but if you wish to support SVG, you can use this superb control: https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation specifically for turning the view into SVG format? Sorry just don't know where to start with this

Comment: You can use + (SVGKImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data;

Comment: looking through the source file now SVGKit now. Says the method is not supported yet?:

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data
{
NSAssert( FALSE, @"Method unsupported / not yet implemented by SVGKit" );
return nil;
}

Comment: Wow, yes I see, you can use + (SVGKImage*) imageWithSource:(SVGKSource *)newSource            and create a new Source from data using + (SVGKSource*)sourceFromData:(NSData*)data;